# I am unable to understand large codes

Tags: wxpython

I have a serious problems understanding large codes please can someone out there give guidance. I have been coding for years but still have that problem.

Comment: There is a [duplicate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215076/whats-the-best-way-to-become-familiar-with-a-large-codebase) that has a lot of good suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to become familiar with a large codebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215076/whats-the-best-way-to-become-familiar-with-a-large-codebase)

Comment: I am unclear how this has anything to do with wxPython...